# Invoking a COM Server Dll on a 64-bit Windows Machine

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, windows-registry, dll

I originally posted this on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567738/invoking-a-com-server-dll-on-a-64-bit-windows-machine), but I thought maybe ServerFault could be a better audience:

I have 32-bit COM exe (written in FoxPro).  This exe invokes a 32-bit COM dll (also written in FoxPro).  In the 32-bit Windows world, the dll is placed in `C:/Windows/System32` directory, registered with `C:/Windows/System32/regsvr32.exe` and all is well.  The exe can be launched and any processes that require the dll are fine.

It's a different story in the 64-bit world.  I tried to install this application on a machine running `Windows 7 x64` like so:

- I place the dll in `C:/Windows/SysWOW64`
- I register it with `C:/Windows/SysWow64/regsvr32.exe`, but I was only able to get the registration to succeed by running `regsvr32` using the "Run As Administrator" context menu option.

Now when I try to run my exe, it is unable to invoke the dll except when my exe is launched using the "Run As Administrator" option.  This is not good.  A user shouldn't be required to be an admin just to run a simple app.

Does anybody know how I can get this to work without requiring the "Run As Administrator" option??

Thank you!

-Ken

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.  See [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567738/invoking-a-com-server-dll-on-a-64-bit-windows-machine) for full answer.

-Ken